# Search/Parse XML and exclude certain nodes without removing them?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

The command below allows me to parse the text in all nodes except for nodes 'wp14:sizeRelH' & 'wp14:sizeRelV'

```
XML.search('//wp14:sizeRelH', '//wp14:sizeRelV').remove.search('//text()')
```

I would like to do the same thing but I do not want to remove nodes 'wp14:sizeRelH' and 'wp14:sizeRelV' from the XML.

This way I can parse through the XML tree and make changes to the text in each node without affecting nodes 'wp14:sizeRelH' and 'wp14:sizeRelV'

EDIT: It appears if nodes '//wp14:sizeRelH' or '//wp14:sizeRelV' are not in the XML, then my command also returns nothing which is not good :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found the answer. I used `//text()[not...]` but had to find the ancestors names of the text I didn't want to include:

```
XML.search('//text()[not(ancestor::wp14:pctHeight or ancestor::wp14:pctWidth or ancestor::wp:posOffset)]')
```